# ui-router, devise and a user profile page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create a user profile page but I'm having some problems. I've used Devise for user handling in my project and I'm using AngularJS and ui-router and obviously RoR.

What I'm trying to do is to show a profile page of a user when the following URL is visited `http://localhost:3000/users/1`

When I visit that URL now I see my frontpage (views/layout/application.html.haml) which is obviously wrong.

In my mainCtrl.js I have

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_search.html',
    controller: 'searchCtrl'
  })
  .state('users.profile', {
    url: '/users/{id}',
    templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_profile.html'
  })
```

The home state works when I go to localhost:3000

But like I said, when I go to `http://localhost:3000/users/1` the template _profile.html doesn't get inserted, there's not even an error if I mistype the template file name. So it looks like the state action doesn't do anything.

My expectation is that the template _profile.html gets loaded into the

```
%div{"ui-view" => ""}
```

on my application.html.haml page. But it inserts the _search template.

And this is the routes.rb if it matters,

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }

  get 'sessions/create'
  get 'sessions/destroy'

  devise_scope :user do
    root to: 'application#angular'
    match '/sessions/user', to: 'devise/sessions#create', via: :post
  end

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end

  resources :relationships,       only: [:create, :destroy]

  get 'login/show'
  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'

  resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :movies, only: [:create, :destroy, :index, :show]

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Researching some examples I noticed the hashtag. When I added the # to my url the route states started working. Then I used html5mode enabled to remove the # and now it's working fine.